# Power PC TRAP - 0700 - Kernel Memory Issue?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded

I am trying to boot the kernel with the nfs root file system. I am suspecting that some memory issue is there. I have a kernel version 4.12.28. This version has a lot of cache changes. I am suspecting that the kernel memory is not initialized properly. This build is using Yocto Sumo with DTC version 4.7. This is a power pc 32 bits architecture. I have shared the .config file here. I am unsure on what is the problem and where to look up.

I have enabled QUOTA, which I think wasn't useful. This system has 512 MB RAM. So, I am not suspecting that it is running out of Memory. Is the dcache_bsize and icache_bsize is sufficient? Is there any thing obvious that I am missing here.

Here is the log -

```
       *## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at f8100000 ...
           Image Name:   Linux-4.12.28
           Created:      2019-07-22   7:01:05 UTC
           Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
           Data Size:    3683596 Bytes = 3.5 MiB
           Load Address: 00000000
           Entry Point:  00000000
           Verifying Checksum ... OK
        ## Flattened Device Tree blob at f8000000
           Booting using the fdt blob at 0xf8000000
           Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
           Loading Device Tree to 007fb000, end 007ff8e8 ... OK
        Linux version 4.12.28 (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) ) #1 Mon Jul 22 00:42:12 UTC 2019
        Using MPC837x RDB/WLAN machine description
        bootconsole [udbg0] enabled
        -----------------------------------------------------
        Hash_size         = 0x0
        phys_mem_size     = 0x20000000
        dcache_bsize      = 0x20
        icache_bsize      = 0x20
        cpu_features      = 0x0000000000020460
          possible        = 0x0000000005a6fd77
          always          = 0x0000000000020000
        cpu_user_features = 0x8c000000 0x00000000
        mmu_features      = 0x00210000
        -----------------------------------------------------
        mpc83xx_setup_arch()
        Zone ranges:
          DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
          Normal   empty
        Movable zone start for each node
        Early memory node ranges
          node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
        Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
        Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
        Kernel command line: console=ttyS1,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw ip=dhcp nfsroot=11.12.98.2:/home/sh/server_rootfs
        PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
        Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
        Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
        Memory: 512064K/524288K available (5852K kernel code, 248K rwdata, 1200K rodata, 172K init, 166K bss, 12224K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
        Kernel virtual memory layout:
          * 0xfffdf000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
          * 0xfdffd000..0xfe000000  : early ioremap
          * 0xe1000000..0xfdffd000  : vmalloc & ioremap
        NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
        IPIC (128 IRQ sources) at e1000700
        clocksource: timebase: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x12049cd416, max_idle_ns: 440795202745 ns
        clocksource: timebase mult[ccccccd] shift[24] registered
        pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
       Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Oops: Exception in kernel mode, sig: 4 [#1]
MPC837x RDB/WLAN
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.12.28-sira-standard #1
task: c06772f0 task.stack: c06a6000
NIP: c01000fc LR: c013f414 CTR: 00000005
REGS: c06a7ce0 TRAP: 0700   Not tainted  (4.12.28-sira-standard)
MSR: 00089032 <EE,ME,IR,DR,RI>
  CR: 24028244  XER: 20000000

GPR00: c013f2e8 c06a7d90 c06772f0 df004e98 00000008 00000001 00000006 00000008
GPR08: 00000000 00000000 00000000 007a1200 84028242 00040000 00000000 00000001
GPR16: 00800300 df416a60 1ffbf05c df414e80 c067c480 ffffffff 00000001 00000000
GPR24: c06c0000 00000000 df416c10 00000000 c013f440 00400000 c0683ba8 df004e98
NIP [c01000fc] set_nlink+0x0/0x58
LR [c013f414] proc_get_inode+0x164/0x190
Call Trace:
[c06a7d90] [c013f2e8] proc_get_inode+0x38/0x190 (unreliable)
[c06a7db0] [c013f4e0] proc_fill_super+0xa0/0x124
[c06a7dd0] [c00e5914] mount_ns+0xa8/0x184
[c06a7e00] [c00e6728] mount_fs+0x24/0xb4
[c06a7e20] [c010581c] vfs_kern_mount.part.8+0x5c/0x158
[c06a7e50] [c0105950] kern_mount_data+0x24/0x50
[c06a7e60] [c013f960] pid_ns_prepare_proc+0x28/0x50
[c06a7e80] [c003e284] alloc_pid+0x4d4/0x4f8
[c06a7ee0] [c0022500] copy_process.isra.7.part.8+0x914/0x12a4
[c06a7f60] [c0023328] _do_fork+0xbc/0x300
[c06a7fa0] [c000409c] rest_init+0x24/0x78
[c06a7fb0] [c06499a0] start_kernel+0x304/0x330
[c06a7ff0] [00003438] 0x3438
Instruction dump:
5cec9cb4 15d573b4 01320182 c865c007 4700e2e1 9303fa22 2f6abc88 24d19205
925583f0 7e007927 f2207002 52600025 <116b5917> 21758908 ac204100 002054e1
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---

Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
Rebooting in 180 seconds..


I want this to mount nfs root file system and run the /sbin/init successfully.*
```

Here is the def config.

[https://docs.google.com/document/d/11XpGHxtEhP9DezyNPYiPqIuPhIpa7y0zF_o4Pl6QkZQ/edit?usp=sharing][kernel config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the kernel is getting an illegal instruction exception (`700` is a `Program` exception - which can be a number of things, but `sig: 4` is `SIGILL`).

There are a number of unimplemented instructions in the `e300` core - double check the compiler you are using to build the kernel is correct and using the right command line options and that the correct cpu options are selected in `.config` (they look ok to me, but I don't know the chip).

Reading [this](https://github.com/ibmruntimes/v8ppc/issues/110) might help (just a random article I found) and check out Appendix B of the [e300coreRM.pdf](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/e300coreRM.pdf).

`[id]cache_bsize` are the cache block (aka line) sizes for instruction and data caches - `0x20` (32 bytes) seems like a reasonable value for that sort of processor.

Comment: The processor is MPC8377.

Comment: Right - I just don’t know much about it so can’t help you with compiler and config options...

Comment: It seems like after reading the link you have shared - the icache and dcache should be 16 rather than 32.

Comment: The article does not mention cache line size, only the cache sizes (both 16KB). 32 byte cache line size seems right to me.